# Java String Special character replacement

Tags: java

I have string which contains alpahanumeric and special character.
I need to replace each and every special char with some string.

For eg,

Input string = "ja*va st&ri%n@&"
Expected o/p = "jaasteriskvaspacestandripercentagenatand"

- = "asterisk"
  & = "and"
  % = "percentage"
  @ = "at"

thanks,

Answer (score 9):

Unless you're absolutely desperate for performance, I'd use a very simple approach:

```
String result = input.replace("*", "asterisk")
                     .replace("%", "percentage")
                     .replace("@", "at"); // Add more to taste :)
```

(Note that there's a big difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` - the latter takes a regular expression. It's easy to get the wrong one and see radically different effects!)

An alternative would be something like:

```
public static String replaceSpecial(String input)
{
    // Output will be at least as long as input
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        switch (c)
        {
            case '*': builder.append("asterisk"); break;
            case '%': builder.append("percentage"); break;
            case '@': builder.append("at"); break;
            default: builder.append(c); break;
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following java.lang.String methods:

- [replace()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))
- [replaceAll()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))