# How to validate Password Field in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am very new for android and in my app I have Validations for Change password page.

That means the Password must contain minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character, for this I tried the code below, but it's not working.

Please help me.

```
if(!isPasswordValidMethod(newPassword.getText().toString())){
           System.out.println("Not Valid");

                }else{

        System.out.println("Valid");
    }



     // Validate password
        private boolean isPasswordValidMethod(String password) {

            String yourString = newPassword.getText().toString();

            System.out.println("yourString is =" + yourString);

            boolean isValid = false;

            // ^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
            // ^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$

            String expression = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$";
            CharSequence inputStr = password;

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                System.out.println("if");
                isValid = true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("else");
            }
            return isValid;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962382/password-validation-adding-additional-requirments

Answer (score 40, accepted):

try following Code

```
 //*****************************************************************
public static boolean isValidPassword(final String password) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=!])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.matches();

}
```

And change your code to this

```
   if(newPassword.getText().toString().length()<8 &&!isValidPassword(newPassword.getText().toString())){
        System.out.println("Not Valid");
      }else{
       System.out.println("Valid");
    }
```

Comment: if(newPassword.getText().toString().length()<8 ||!isValidPassword(newPassword.getText().toString())){
       System.out.println("Not Valid");

Comment: that is validate condition

Comment: minimum 8 characters means it must be "&&" not ||

Comment: What would be conditions for this pattern like password must contain min 8 characters, must be alpha numeric,must contain at least one symbol. Like this? @mdDroid

Comment: For anyone that wants to know ... The regex represents the need for user to enter atleast `1 Uppercase, 1 Number and 1 Symbol`.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static boolean isValidPassword(String s) {
            Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN
                    = Pattern.compile(
                    "[a-zA-Z0-9\\!\\@\\#\\$]{8,24}");

            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
        }
```

to use it,

```
if(isValidPassword(password)){ //password valid}
```

You can set whatever symbol that you allowed here

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean passwordCharValidation(String passwordEd) {
    String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@_.]).*$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(passwordEd);
    if (!passwordEd.matches(".*\\d.*") || !matcher.matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is you answer full-fill :It contains minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character.Thanks

Comment: yes Firstly check passwordEd length greater then 8 if(passwordEd.length() > 8);

Answer (score 2):

```
  String validPassword = "12345";
                     _Password_String = Password.getText().toString();
                    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(validPassword).matcher(_Password_String);
                    if (matcher.matches()) {
                        Log.e("d11", _Password_String);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Password Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();


                    } else {
                        Password.setError("Password");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Password not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works

```
   public static boolean isPasswordValidMethod(final String password) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$""
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.matches();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without using Regex. Here is the code part :

```
private fun hasUpperCase(data: CharSequence): Boolean {
    val password = data.toString()
    return password.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) == password
}

private fun hasLowerCase(data: CharSequence): Boolean {
    val password = data.toString()
    return password.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT) == password
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easy piece of code for email field validation and password validation and check for minimum 8 characters in password field.

```
  if (isValidEmail(et_regemail.getText().toString())&&etpass1.getText().toString().length()>7){
      if (validatePassword(etpass1.getText().toString())) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Go Ahead".....
      }
      else{

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"InvalidPassword".....
       }

}else{

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Email".....
}


public boolean validatePassword(final String password){
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.* 
    [@#$%^&+=!])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.matches();
}

public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null)
        return false;

    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and sort, just use below method for checking valid password,

```
public static boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!]).{4,20})").matcher(password);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

and you can use this method as below

```
          if (!isValidPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                errorDialog("Password must contain mix of upper and lower case letters as well as digits and one special charecter(4-20)");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPasswordValidMethodTrueOrFalse(final String password) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String THE_REAL_PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$""
    pattern = Pattern.compile(THE_REAL_PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.matches(); 
}
```

Comment: Please add explanations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same warning 4 times after pasting the code from [@yuzuriha's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7676003/yuzuriha) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44252561/19610655) into Android Studio.
The warning is:

> Redundant character escape '\!' in RegExp

Next I cut the unnecessary characters according to warning and check if the string has length 8 or more.

Now my updated code is:

```
    private boolean isValidPassword(String s) {
    Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$]{8,24}");
    return s.length() >= 8 && PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**Passwords do not match**

```
if  (password.getText().toString() != reEnteredPassword.getText().toString()) {
//not match
}
```

**For Empty Fields**

```
if (password.getText().toString().isEmpty() || reEnteredPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
//Fieds empty error message
```

**Less than 8 characters**

```
if ((password.getText().toString().length() < 8) || (reEnteredPassword.getText().toString().length() < 8)) {
// less than 8 characters error message
}
```

**Not having special characters**

```
if (!password.getText().toString().matches( "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=?-]).{8,15}$") || !reEnteredPassword.getText().toString().matches( "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=?-]).{8,15}$")){
//not having special characters error message
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.